# Trying to access table value within the table

Tags: lua

I'm trying to do this

```
local ball = {
        width = 20,
        height = 20,

        position = {
            x = (game.width / 2) - (width / 2), -- Place the ball at the center of the screen
            y = (game.height / 2) - (height / 2)
        },

        velocity = 200,
        color = { 255, 255, 255 }
    }
```

But Love2D say me `attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'width' (a nil value)`. How can I fix it?
I already tried to replace `width / 2` with `ball.width / 2` but I got `attempt to index global 'ball' (a nil value)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `local some_name = expression` is equivalent to:

```
local some_name
some_name = expression
```

This allows `some_name` to appear in `expression`. In particular, it allows recursion with local functions. However, until `expression` is actually finished being evaluated, the *value* of `some_name` is still `nil`.

So within your table initialization, `ball` is a `nil` value. There is no way to access members of a table while that table is being initialized. You can however do so afterwards:

```
local ball = {
    width = 20,
    height = 20,


    velocity = 200,
    color = { 255, 255, 255 }
}

ball.position = {
    x = (game.width / 2) - (ball.width / 2), -- Place the ball at the center of the screen
    y = (game.height / 2) - (ball.height / 2)
}
```